# Find out where a google form was opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form that is a survey to ask if a document was helpful or not. There is a link to the google form in multiple documents.

Is there a way to find out:

- Which document the survey was opened from?

OR

- Prefill the google form with which document the survey was opened from?

Comment: What do you mean by "housed"? in multiple "documents"?

Comment: @TheMaster, I think he meant the same form is used in multiple sheets. But it makes no sense since it is not possible.

Comment: Hi @AllisterLobo, the issue is you can only link a form to a single sheet. Can you show your current script that opens the form from a "document"? Although you can find out where the response is written out by executing `FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId()`. It returns the spreadsheet ID where it contains the responses of the form. That's all I can provide now since I'm not entirely sure how you can open a survey from a document though (aside from creating one from there).

Comment: I believe the op has embedded the form in different locations and they wish to know which one is the current submitter.  Unfortunately, I don't believe their is a soluion

Comment: @TheMaster let's say the document is a Google Doc then there will be a link of the survey in the Google Doc.

Comment: @NaziA I don't have a script now I'm just browsing ideas. The link to the Google Form is just in multiple Google Docs at the end of each document.

Comment: I suggest you pre-fill using url parameters of the pre-filled form link. I'll try to show the answer below.

Comment: I have provided an answer below @AllisterLobo. Kindly check below, it should be easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Get pre-filled link" option on the form.

1. Get pre-filled link
   [image: prefill]
2. Write the pre-filled answer then get the link
   [image: answer]
3. You should have a link like this
   `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSffj8oplUxNJDNxJlqmYVELlfM11WPeoUeYUPSWO1h0gCodxQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1415671424=English+Document`
4. Then just modify the url parameter containing the pre-filled answer and paste that to other documents (sample, having **Math** instead of **English** instead)
   `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSffj8oplUxNJDNxJlqmYVELlfM11WPeoUeYUPSWO1h0gCodxQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1415671424=Math+Document`

Opening the link will result into this:
[image: output]

- Just do step 4 repeatedly until you generate all links for all the needed documents.

#### Reference:

- [Send a form with pre-filled answers](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308781?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

> Prefill the google form with which document the survey was opened from?

Yes, in a roundabout way. You can add a question to your form 'Redirected from:' or however you want to phrase it, and have it set as multiple choice, one answer for each location you expect it to be coming from.  I would recommend this as a separate section, making it as the last section, and change the previous section from 'Continue to next section' to 'Submit'.  This way the user never sees the question.

Once you have your new section with the one question in it, select more (pancake menu) "Get pre-filled link". Now you just need to click each answer, and click 'Get Link'.  This will generate a prefilled link that you can then use where you share the link from.  For example, if you have the form link in a Google Doc, Google Sheet, and Google Slide, and you want to see which one the user came from - your multiple choice answers would be Doc, Sheet, Slide.  You would generate a prefilled answer of Doc, get the link, and then post the link into your doc where the current form link is now. Then generate a second link with a prefilled answer for Sheet, and paste that link into the sheet where the current link is now.  Here is more information on [prefilled forms](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308781?hl=en).